# Adding Events to the calendar view Dynamically in android

Tags: android, events, calendarview, caldroid

We are trying to add Events to the calendar view dynamically in android by exploring Extended calendar view library,caldroid master library and other such libraries but we didn't get the solution. These are the following links which we have explored:

https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView

https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

Suggest us the proper way to add events to the calendar view   dynamically